# getItemCount() method in my adapter has an error

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am new to this and still haven't fully grasped this adapter. From the error it seems that since its null my guess is that I would probably have to initialize the list. The problem is i'm a little confused as to how and why since i'm getting the list from api. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated

If you need more information let me know so I can provide it

Here is my main activity

```
public class KeanTrolley extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kean_trolley);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)));
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "COMING SOON", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());


    StationService stationService = StationServiceProvider.createService(StationService.class);
    Call<List<stations>> call = stationService.listStations();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<stations>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<List<stations>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            mAdapter = new StationsAdapter(response.body());
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Here is my adapter class

```
public class StationsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StationsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public Context context;

private List<stations> mStations;
//Context mContext;

public StationsAdapter(List<stations> station) {
    mStations = station;
    //mContext = context;

}
@Override
public StationsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.rv_card_item, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(StationsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    stations stationLoc = mStations.get(position);
    holder.TvStationName.setText(stationLoc.getmStationName());
    holder.IvStationPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.kean_logo_1);
    holder.mCardView.setTag(position);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mStations.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView TvStationName;
    public ImageView IvStationPic;
    public View mCardView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        TvStationName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.station_name);
        IvStationPic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.station_photo);

        mCardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        mCardView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = (int) v.getTag();

        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Trolley_Activity.class);
        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), Integer.toString(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
}
}
```

Here is the error

```
11-20 21:25:58.688 18393-18393/com.example.ogure.keantransport E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.ogure.keantransport, PID: 18393
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.example.ogure.keantransport.Adapter.StationsAdapter.getItemCount(StationsAdapter.java:56)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2556)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:610)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:78)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1109)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:675)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Your 'mStations' object is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to change it as ..

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return null!=mStations?mStations.size():0;
}
```

i am sure you are getting the null list .. 'mStations'.

And you should check the list where you are setting the adapter(StationsAdapter). May be you are passing the null list as argument

**Edits :**

```
@Override
    public void onResponse(Response<List<stations>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
if(response.body()==null){
             // show some error message
       }else{
        mAdapter = new StationsAdapter(response.body());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
    }
```

Comment: I tried the first solution and although the app does not crash, it doesn't populate my RecyclerView either. So I do think the problem lies in my main Activity. I will update it can you take a quick look at it

Comment: ok try to put log here 
`//here try to print the response list Log.e("response.body()",response.body());`
`mAdapter = new StationsAdapter(response.body());`

Comment: and see the logcat in red fonts "response.body()" Tag. what list you are getting there?

Comment: I just checked my server is down, which is probably why its returning null. For future reference how should i handle this potential error so the app does not crash but rather give some sort of feedback to the user

Comment: here you can check 'response.body()!=null?Call the adapter : show some error message`

Answer (score 0):

Please check your code in this section :-

```
StationService stationService = StationServiceProvider.createService(StationService.class);
Call<List<stations>> call = stationService.listStations();
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<stations>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<List<stations>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        mAdapter = new StationsAdapter(response.body());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

Here in the onResponse() method, you're passing response.body() as a list for stations. That response.body() method might be returning a null list which is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was doing this:

```
public FavQuotesCards(ArrayList<Quote> quotes) {
  quotes = quotes;
}
```

instead of:

```
public FavQuotesCards(ArrayList<Quote> quotes) {
  this.quotes = quotes;
}
```

Can you believe it?